# Im not able to use internet in oracle virtual box ubuntu with host windows 7 via usb

Tags: ubuntu, internet, connection, tethering

i recently installed ubuntu in VB with hos as windows 7 32 bit and im not able to use internet in ubuntu and I normally use internet in windows via usb tethering with a smartphone ..

Answer (score 0):

Open VirtualBox. In the left pane, you'll see your VM (Ubuntu). 
Right click on it, select settings. 
In settings, go to "Network" ---> "Adaptor 1" 
Click "Enable Network Adaptor" 
Attached to : "NAT" 
Click "Advanced" drop down 
Make sure "Cable Connected" is enabled